# How to redirect url like "http://www.example.com/pathquery-string=something" to error page using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to redirect url like "http://www.example.com/pathstring=something" to error page using htaccess file.
"http://www.example.com/path" this is part of url and "string=something" is part of query string.
if someone misses the "?" in query string, the page should redirect to error page.
Here is my htaccess code

```
 RewriteEngine on  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you share the htaccess code you have so far? so that we know how to help you better

Comment: hi paul, shared htaccess code as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
RewriteRule ^path([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /error-page.html [R=301,L]
```

If there is no "?" after **path**, it'll redirect to error page

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, there is no way http://www.example.com/pathstring=something will redirect to a rewrite rule with: http://www.example.com/path?string=something.

However, if http://www.example.com/pathstring=something is not a valid URL and no rewrite rule of that path in your .htaccess, you can redirect to all not found pages to a 404 page. Add this to you .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
ErrorDocument 404 /my-404-page.html
```